# Gulp tasks defined into a dependency module are not reachable

Tags: gulp

I have tasks I would like to share across several projects, so I moved them inside another module, which I load from my target project's `gulpfile.js`.

Project A tree:

```
gulpfile.js
package.json
...
```

gulpfile.js:

```
require('my-gulp-tasks')({
  version: '0.0.1',
  production: utils.env.production,
  port: ...
  // misc settings to customize tasks
});
```

My gulp tasks module tree:

```
index.js
tasks/
  clean.js
  assets.js
  ...
```

index.js *(simplified version)*:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

module.exports = function (settings) {
  //...

  gulp.task('clean', require('./tasks/clean')(settings));

  return gulp;
}
```

But when I ask for the known tasks from within "Project A" with `gulp -T`, the command's output is empty...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working by passing a `gulp` instance from the `gulpfile` to the module, and avoiding to require gulp locally.

I ended up with:

Project A:

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

require('my-gulp-tasks')(gulp, {
  // settings...
});
```

My gulp tasks module:

index.js:

```
module.exports = function (gulp, settings) {
  //...

  gulp.task('clean', require('./tasks/clean')(settings));

  return gulp;
}
```

clean.js:

```
var rm = require('gulp-rm');

module.exports = function (gulp) {
  return function () {
    return gulp.src('dist/**/*').pipe(rm());
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings! I was wondering how to do this and you saved me a bunch of time.